# How do you access a child method

Tags: php

How do you access a child method eg.?

```
class A
{
    public function Start()
    {
        // Somehow call Run method on the B class that is inheriting this class
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function Run()
    {
        ...
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->Start(); // Which then should call Run method
```

Comment: `$this->Run();` but your design is flawed

Comment: @ zerkms `$this->Run();` would not work if called from class A as it has no knowledge of a `Run()` function. But yes, your point stands, design is flawed.

Comment: It's not my design, it's the pthread design. PHP threading stuff, I was just wondering how it worked. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 Perhaps you copied/pasted the code wrong? You can't call `Run()` by chaining(if that's what you wish to do) via `Start()` as it resides in class A and has no knowledge of `Run()` method.

Comment: I missed out the abstract, and that's why it didn't make sense. See deceze answer. Thanks all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Class `A` should not try to call any methods that it itself does not define. This will work just fine for your scenario:

```
class A {
    public function Start() {
        $this->Run();
    }
}
```

However, it will fail terribly should you actually do this:

```
$a = new A;
$a->Start();
```

What you're trying to do here sounds very much like a use case for `abstract` classes:

```
abstract class A {
    public function Start() {
        $this->Run();
    }

    abstract function Run();
}

class B extends A {
    public function Run() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `abstract` declaration will precisely prevent you from shooting your own foot by trying to instantiate and `Start` `A` without extending and defining required methods.

Comment: Ah that's the one, the abstract part. Cheers buddy.

Answer (score 0):

If B is inherited from A then B will be like:

```
      class B extends A
{
    public function Start()
    {
        ...
    }
    public function Run()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So as Run() and Start() are in the same class, we can call Run() in Start() directly.

```
public function Start()
{
    Run();
}
```